# How to set default size of page in firefox developer edition

Tags: firefox, macbook-pro-retina, firefox-developer-tools

I use Firefox Developer Edition on my Macbook pro retina. However, Firefox doesn't support finger pinch in and out page enlargement like safari and chrome. I have to do that from top bar. How can I set the size to 133% for all pages(default)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need-

1. Enter`about:config` in the firefox address bar (confirm the info message in case it shows up)

2.Search for the preference  named `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx`.

3.Double-click it and change its value to 1.0 (or any other zoom factor that fits your purpose; -1.0 is the default value and will adhere to the system settings).

Comment: this doesn't work